# Why Ubuntu in a VM won't find my FPGA?

Tags: virtualbox, windows-8.1, ubuntu-10.04

I use Ubuntu in a Virtual Box VM to run Quartus II to run programs with the Altera DE2 FPGA. Now I upgraded to Windows 8.1 and the guest os (ubuntu 10) won't find the DE2 board. I think that maybe it's because the host os (Win 8.1) can't even find it and I wonder if that is a general case, that a guest operating system can't find the hardware unless the host operating system can? Or is the cause for the issue something else and related to ubuntu in the VM and has nothing to do with the Win 8.1 environment? I probably can install the driver and make Win 8.1 find the DE2 board, but I want to know why the guest os doesn't find the FPGA?

[image]

### Update 140328 11:48 CET

It works now. I reinstalled everything, even tried with older versions of VB but that got worse. Now I could add the FPGA so that the Nios II finds it in the guest os.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking up the DE2 on Altera's website, it appears that it connects to your computer via USB.

Remember that a virtual machine is effectively a whole separate computer, with its own (virtual) network interface and its own (virtual) USB ports.  Initially, your DE2 is plugged into the Windows host computer, *not* the VM.  There should be a menu option in VirtualBox to connect it to the VM instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get it recognized by the virtual environment, you might look into the Quartus's ability to remotely program over a TCP/IP connection to the computer where the USB Blaster driver (and Quartus Programming service) is.

Comment: It finally works now. I don't run the latest version of everything but it's a combination that supports the entire toolchain (C/asm, Nios II IDE, Quartus II v10, Ubunt 10, latest VB. I didn't have to remove the driver from the host os. The issue seems could have been that saved stataes from the old host os (Win 7 on Sony Vaio) got saved and duplicated with the new host os and hw (Asus Zenbook) which uses usb 3.

Answer (score 0):

I also looked up information on several sites about the multiple programs in use. From what I found in some cases minor program changes had to be made, different versions, some had to make a program change on 8.1. All information I obtained was from the individual sites and chat help sites of each program listed. I wasn't sure if I could drop the links or not. That's why I didn't to give you the exact location of information I found.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I reinstalled everything and now the gues os finds the FPGA from within the VM. I did not have to disable the driver in the host os (win 8.1) and I can do it with the latest version of VB. I use ubuntu 10 and quartus 10 but perhaps this can also be done with ubuntu 13 and quartus 13 - I've seen nothing that the latest versions of this particular combination can work (but it looks like Altera is already dropping support for DE" in favor of the Cyclone III and V models).